# configuring the InputField as an IP address field in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi2,

Does anyone know how to configure an Input Field in Unity as an IP address field ?

I was using this kind of structure by using 3 input fields as a work around.
[image]

However what i would like to have is something like this:
Using only 1 InputField and the "dot" is automatically placed when the user enter the ip address.

[image]

Comment: Please note that IP adresses consist 4 sections, separated with dots.
And how do you want to separate your data in case, when first number consists only 2 digits, for example 55.168.1.1? How to avoid wrong parsing to 551.68...?

Comment: First a small remark: IP4 addresses consist of four parts, not three (e.g 192.168.0.1). That said implementing something that would automatically place the dots is quite tricky. this because it is very hard to predict where they need to be, as IP addresses are not bound to xxx.yyy.z.w format. But can also be formatted like xxx.yy.zzz.www

Comment: I have updated the pictures. Thank you for the remainder... ^_^

Comment: I have updated the picture, my bad... (ﾉ≧ڡ≦)
at first i thought that using **Regex** will be possible to solve this problem., but it turns out no. any idea.. ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to parse IP, just validate input like this (don't forget to add this script to your inputfield

```
    string ip = gameObject.text;
    string[] ipStringArr = ip.Split('.');
    int[] ipIntArr = new int[ipStringArr.Length];
    if (ipIntArr.Length != 4)
    {
        //error
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ipStringArr.Length; i++)
        {
            ipIntArr[i] = Int32.Parse(ipStringArr[i]);
            if (ipIntArr[i] < 0 || ipIntArr[i] > 255)
            {
                //error
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Or you can use Regex
 ^(?!0)(?!.*\.$)((1?\d?\d|25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d)(\.|$)){4}$

Comment: The question isn't about parsing though. OP is asking how to automatically add the dots. There is a native [parse function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2) that can be used for validating aswel.

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be best handled with a RegEx data annotation on your model.

```
[RegularExpression(@ "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]| 
[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$")]  
public string IPAddress  
{  
    get;  
    set;  
}
```

Then you'll need to add Html.EditorFor and Html.ValidationMessageFor and Html.ValidationSummary helpers in your view.

MVC will wire up the appropriate client side validation scripting for you.  Of course you'll want to validate server side in your controller too.

```
if (ModelState.IsValidField("IPAddress"))
{
  -- Do something...  Good IP address
}
```

Here is a great article that explains it all.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/data-annotations-and-validation-in-mvc/